# If you expose a Rest API, are you also supposed to provide the DTOs in popular languages?

Tags: dto, rest

If I expose a Rest end point that anyone can consume. For argument sake let's say it accepts a ticker symbol and I return a json string that has information on that, for example the ceo, stock price and year founded.

```
{
  "symbol": "Abc",
  "ceo": "Elon Musket",
  "stock price": "$50",
  "year founded": "2023"
}
```

Am I supposed to provide DTOs that can be consumed in Java, C# and other popular languages (for deserializing)? Is that a common practice? Or anyone who consumes my service is supposed to create their own DTOs?

Answer (score 0):

[A DTO (Data Transfer Object)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) is a design pattern for any object used to transfer multiple data values between remote systems. JSON is a DTO, which is handled just fine by [pretty much every language that would be able to receive it](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

If you are worried about best REST API practices, [check out the stackoverflow page on the exact topic.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/)